Interpreting Coefficients in 2SLS Model
I am currently working on a 2SLS model where I instrumented the logarithm of per capita transfers with the unemployment rate from each country that the transfers originate from (also taking logarithms—this is the first stage of my 2SLS). In the second stage, I looked at how these instrumented transfers (independent variable) affect per capita employment -not in logarithms- (dependent variable). The resulting coefficient was 0.05.
How should I interpret this coefficient of 0.05? Additionally, could anyone recommend literature or examples that discuss similar findings or methodologies?
Thanks in advance for your insights!
I have not found formal literature that tells me how to interpret the coefficient

This is not a programming question. It's a statistics or econometrics question about interpreting your results. You would be better off on Statalist, but expect to be asked to show much more detail.
